# DIV won't hide on mobile devices using media query

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am trying to make a certain page on our website mobile-friendly by hiding two large divs that aren't supposed to display as they are a) interactive and feature hover effects, and b) break up the flow of the page.

Currently testing on my LG G2 in Chrome, using

```html
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {
div.example {
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden;
}
}
```

However it has no effect at all.

The CSS for "example" is:

```html
div.example {
background-image: url('http://www.example.com/example.jpg'); border: 3px solid #ecf0f1; 
height: 941px; 
width: 1209px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? As you can see by the dimensions they are too big for a standard mobile device... the page looks perfect on iPad & desktop resolutions, and even the forced requested desktop site version displays fine in mobile.

Any help appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution of [LG G2](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_g2-5543.php) is 1080 x 1920, which is larger than `max-width: 768px`. Your media query failed. Use:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 1080px) {
}
```

for portrait orientation of the device. Even better, you can make use of: `-webkit-device-pixel-ratio` to target devices with different pixel ratio.

FYI, LG G2 has `webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3` (see [Reference](http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/))

**Update:** Here is a general media query for high pixel ratio devices:

https://gist.github.com/marcedwards/3446599

Comment: Thanks @Raptor ; yes I just realised this afterwards when looking at the device specs. Unfortunately I upped it to 1080p wide and it still didn't work on the phone, HOWEVER it DID work in removing the DIV from the iPad I was testing on. Feel like I can't win here as I DO want it to display on tablets (the iPad is an older non-retina version so 1080p is enough to block the content on the tablet). Would you recommend device to pixel ratio instead of pixel-based media queries in general? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend device to pixel ratio instead of width, as devices may falsely identified.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) { div.example { display: none; } }
div.example {
background-image: url('http://scholarship-positions.com/internships/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/google.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border: 3px solid #ecf0f1;
height: 941px; 
width: 1209px; 
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto; 
background-color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="example"></div>
</body>
</html>
```